# Django заполнение базы данных из json файла (начальные данные)

Tags: python, django, django-model

Подскажите, есть, ли, готовые решения для заполнения базы данных из `json`-файла.

Класс модели выглядит вот так

```py
class ServiceForEnd(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    methods = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id_request = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    oData = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    id_obligatory = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

содержание `json`:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "ReportingTrialBalance",
        "url": "Reporting/TrialBalance/",
        "methods": "GET",
        "id_request": false,
        "oData": true,
        "id_obligatory": false
    },
    {
        "name": "BankTransfer",
        "url": "Bank/BankTransfer/",
        "methods": "GET, POST, DELETE",
        "id_request": true,
        "oData": true,
        "id_obligatory": false
    }
]
```

Comment: Заполнения откуда и с какой целью? Возможно, вам нужны [fixtures](https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/howto/initial-data.html)?

Comment: @andreymal initial заполнение при развертывании

Comment: Тогда да, для этого и есть fixtures

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, гляну

Answer (score 1, accepted):

да, можно написать комманду под `manage.py`
Для этого понадобится `BaseCommand`
Ниже пример кода для заполнения таблиц `Genre` и `Subgenre` моего проекта

Сам файл находится по пути:

```
├───books_website
│   ├───books
│   │   ├───management
│   │   │   ├───commands
│   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   │─── load_data.py
```

```
from itertools import count
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import json
from books.models import Genre, SubGenre

    
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        with open('books.json', 'rb') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            
            for i in data:
                print(i)
                genre = Genre()
                genre.name = i
                genre.save()
                
                g = Genre.objects.values('id').get(name = i)['id']
                for j in data.get(i):
                    s = SubGenre()
                    s.name = j
                    s.save()
                    s.genres.add(g)
        print('finished')
```

Запуск через:

```
python manage.py load_data
```

Answer (score 0):

По наводке @andreymal воспользовался [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures), специально предназначенной для загрузки начальных (initial) данных в базу. Поддерживаются форматы файлов `json`, `YAML`.

Как это провернуть:

1. Переработал свой `json` файл к виду

```json
[
    {
        "model": "app.serviceforend",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "name": "ReportingTrialBalance",
            "url": "Reporting/TrialBalance/",
            "methods": "{'GET'}",
            "id_request": false,
            "oData": true,
            "id_obligatory": false
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "app.serviceforend",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "name": "BankTransfer",
            "url": "Bank/BankTransfer/",
            "methods": "{'GET'}",
            "id_request": false,
            "oData": true,
            "id_obligatory": false
        }
    }
]
```

2. Создал папку `fixtures` в каталоге приложения и положил туда файл. Папка должна называться именно так, для автоматического поиска, но есть возможность указать просто путь к файлу.
3. Выполнил следующее

```
~/path_to_manage$ python3 manage.py loaddata a.json
```

4. Получил ответ об успешности внесения 102 записей в таблицу.